# How do I enable NVENC for video output?

Tags: hardware, encoding

I'm trying to speed up my render times. One option is that I can use Optix, which should have some benefit. The other is enabling NVENC hardware encoding for the video. Strangely though I can't see option anywhere at all in the video format/codec section. Could someone please tell me what I need to do to enable this function. Thanks.

Comment: Don't think you can.  See https://blender.community/c/vse/Wq3x/?sorting=hot -- a request that never got a response.

Comment: I confirm you can't. To be honest, the implementation of FFMPEG (the lib responsible for video encoding in Blender) is made way slower than what FFMPEG can be so I wouldn't recommand using Blender's video encoding beyond low resolution fast previewing.

Comment: I also don't think that encoding video should be a core task of Blender. This should be done in a production chain by a program that specializes in it, and Blender should rather take care of the further development of other important features (there is enough to do, after all).

Comment: But it IS already dealt with by a specialized program: ffmpeg. The issue of Blender is that is doesn't use it anywhere near its full potential. All the BF devs need to do is work on the UI to at least give access to what FFMPEG offers by its own already.